# Itertools Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there any way to use itertools product function where the function returns each combination of lists step by step ?

For example:
`itertools.product(*mylist)`
-> the solution should return the first combination of the lists , after that the second one etc.

Comment: Can you provide an example input and an expected output? It's kind of up to us to guess what you mean without it

Comment: All `itertools` functions return iterators, so you can just say `it = itertools.product(my_list)` and call `it.next()` to get the next item in the iterator.

Comment: Whoops--I meant `next(it)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ggorlen has explained, `itertools.product(...)` returns an [iterator](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp). For example, if you have

```
import itertools
mylist = [('Hello','Hi'),('Andy','Betty')]
iterator = itertools.product(*mylist)
```

`next(iterator)` or `iterator.__next__()` will evaluate to `'Hello Andy'` the first time you call them, for example. When you next call `next(iterator)`, it will return `'Hello Betty'`, then `'Hi Andy'`, and finally `'Hi Betty'`, before raising `StopIteration` errors.

You can also convert an `iterator` into a `list` with `list(iterator)`, if you are more comfortable with a `list`, but if you just need the first few values and `mylist` is big, this would be really inefficient, and it might be worth the time familiarising yourself with iterators.

Do consider whether you are really just iterating through `iterator` though. If so, just use

```
for combination in iterator:
    pass # Body of loop
```

Even if you just need the first `n` elements and `n` is large you can use

```
for combination in itertools.islice(iterator, n):
    pass # Body of loop
```